# How can I filter a list and take square numbers out in haskell

Tags: haskell

imagine that we have a list and we would want to take only square number out of list

```
isSquare :: Int -> Bool
isSquare n = truncate(sqrt(x)) * truncate(sqrt(x)) == n
         where x = fromIntegral n


squareTriSemi = filter (isSquare) triSeries
```

here is definition of triSeries

```
triSeries 0 = [0]
triSeries n = map triangular $take n $iterate (+1) 1
where triangular x = x * (x + 1) `div` 2
```

but it does not compile it complains like this

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Int]' with actual type `Int -> [t0]'
    In the second argument of `filter', namely `triSeries'
    In the expression: filter (isSquare) triSeries
    In an equation for `squareTriSemi':
        squareTriSemi = filter (isSquare) triSeries
```

any help ?

Comment: Remember, you can accept the working answer with the special button.

Answer (score 4):

Your definition of `triSeries` takes an `Int` and returns a list. That is, `triSeries` by itself is not a list, but an expression like `triSeries 10` is a list.

One way to fix your definition of `squareTriSemi` is to add a parameter which is passed to `triSeries`:

```
squareTriSeries n = filter isSquare (triSeries n)
```